# Portable Windows browser with good multimedia downloading built-in

Tags: windows, gratis, web-browser, portable

I like to use [Torch Browser](http://www.torchbrowser.com/) which is basically Chrome with some built-in functionality to download multimedia - straight out of the box, no plug-ins required.

Unfortunately, extensive googling has found a lot of junk sites which claim to have a portable version, but don't. The absence of such a thing on both the Torch site and http://portableapps.com/ convinces me that it doesn’t exist.

Can anyone suggest an alternative?

---

[Update] Thanks for the suggestion, @Alejandro, but I would rather not have to launch a VM specifically for this porpoise.

**MUST**
 - run on Windows
 - be gratis
 - be portable

**Highly desirable**
 - can download multi-media without the need for extra plug-ins or configuration

Comment: For the vast majority of programs, making a portable version is just a matter of installing it temporarily (in a disposable VM if needed) and copying its `program files` folder out of it. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Comodo Dragon](https://www.comodo.com/home/browsers-toolbars/browser.php)

Comodo Dragon is another web browser based on Chromium. It comes with a built in media downloader.

**Features**:

- Runs on Windows
- Gratis
- Has a portable version<sup>12</sup>.
- Comes with an [integrated media downloader](https://help.comodo.com/topic-120-1-279-6885-.html)

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> The portable version is seleced during installation (same setup file as the non-portable version) [image]

<sup>2</sup> Note that you still need admin privileges to install and update the browser, but after that, it can run on a USB stick or copied between computers.